# C# Correct Rounding Taking Into Account All the Digits

Tags: c#, rounding

I use decimal variables in c#

I want to get `Math.round(0.004449m, 2) = 0.01`

I mean start rounding from the last digit ie: 9 in this example. Since `Math.round(0.004449m, 5) = 0.00445` treat 0.004449m as 0.0445 at the first place.

Keep rounding. Since `Math.round(0.0445m , 4) = 0.045` treat 0.0445m as 0.045

Finally `Math.round(0.004449m, 2)` is found to be 0.01.

I know this approach is mathematically wrong but there is also a logic behind it so my company decided to round numbers like this.

Is there this kind of function in .net?

Comment: Erm... No, there's nothing built-in to do this weird quasi-rounding

Comment: your "correct rounding" is not at all mathematically _correct_. i'm curious as to what the logic behind this decision _is_ - i can only imagine scamming your customers in ways your company hopes they won't notice. and, as canton already said, there is no built-in function in C# - you have to implement it on your own.

Comment: well, you could probably do a for-loop based on the number of decimal places and round each one (make extension method or something), but yeah... don't do that. Round properly

Comment: It's basically a test that your number is `> 0.44444...` recurring (with leading zeros as required) I think? Perhaps you can build your logic around that.

Comment: Are you sure your question is written correctly? Even following the logic you describe, if you started with 0.004449 you would get 0.01 and not 0.05. 

Even if this is an error, it's a bit beside the point. This isn't rounding. It certainly isn't "correct" rounding. Perhaps you could explain the reason for using this approach in the first place?

Comment: I would note that there might be laws governing how rounding may be performed.

Comment: I would assume the question could be simplified to "round `0.49` to `1` instead of `0` by using the intermediate rounding to `0.5`".

Comment: @JonasH Not quite? It rounds 0.449 to 1, even though the intermediate rounding of 0.449 is 0.0

Comment: @canton7 you probably need the AwayFromZero midpoint rounding mode for the scheme to work. Running `Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Reverse().Aggregate(0.4449, (v, a) => System.Math.Round(v, a, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))` would produce `1`

Comment: Fortunately no, there is no built-in .NET function for this. I say fortunately because describing this operation in mathematical terms of the ultimate outcome, rather than in operational terms, is quite complicated; documenting, testing and explaining such a function would be a nightmare. If your company wants this, those tasks fall to you.

Comment: A new [The Daily WTF](https://thedailywtf.com/) entry is going to be born. So excited.